# Set binsize for a barchart in dc.js

Tags: d3.js, data-visualization, dc.js, crossfilter

I have a dataset of patients where each patient has an age.

I have a barchart which displays the patient age which is generated with the following code:

```
     /*Age Bar Chart*/
            var ageDim = cf1.dimension(dc.pluck('leeftijd'));//define age dimension
            var ageGroup = ageDim.group().reduceCount();//define age group
            var ageChart = dc.barChart('#ageBarChart'); //link chart to DOM
            ageChart
            .dimension(ageDim)
            .colors('#542788')
            .group(ageGroup)
            .x(d3.scale.linear().domain([15,75]))
                .gap(1)//gap between bars
                .xAxisLabel("Leeftijd in jaren")
                .yAxisLabel("Aantal Patiënten");
                ageChart.render();
```

My question is as follows: How can i change the binsize, so that instead of showing how many people are within agegroup 43 it display age per groups of 5. So it will show the amount of people that are within age 40-45.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what the group's value function is for (sort of the "map" part of map-reduce).

You can specify that each age should fall into the low end of the range like this:

```
var ageGroup = ageDim.group(function(age) {
    return Math.floor(age/5)*5;
}).reduceCount();//define age group
```

Now you'll get bins at 0, 5, 10, etc.

Comment: This works however the width of the bar is tiny, how do i get that to fill up between 2 ticks. I have 0 gap at the moment

Comment: fixed it by using a negative gap

Comment: [xUnits](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/develop/web/docs/api-latest.md#coordinategridmixinxunitsxunits--function--coordinategridmixin) controls the bar width